# Python + MongoDB - Error while querying twitter messages using new DB

Tags: python, mongodb, twitter

I am new to Python + MongoDB and currently working on a query to search for tweets (twitter_message) from a variety of profiles (twitter_profile) which are included in a list as a part of my masters dissertation.

I had a DB that used the following format:

```
 "_id": ObjectId("557830f2b9ba7a2e7425d8db")
   "create_at": "null"
   "id": 1620930714
   "friendships": Array [0]
   "versions": Array [2]
```

And my query with this DB structure would be:

```
for profile in listProfiles:
     profile_id = db.mongo.get_one(collection='twitter_profile', where={'versions.screen_name':profile}, select={'id':True, '_id':0})        
        listProfilesId.append(profile_id['id'])    
    AllTweetsFromProfile = []    
    for iProfile in range(0,len(listProfilesId)):
        profile_id = listProfilesId[iProfile]
        tweets = db.mongo.get_all(collection='twitter_message', where={'profile':profile_id}, select={'text':True, '_id':0})      
        for tweet in tweets:
            AllTweetsFromProfile.append(tweet['text'])
        tweetsProfile[listProfile[iProfile]] = AllTweetsFromProfile
```

And it worked very fine until I changed the DB structure for something like this:

```
    "_id": 61884410
       "_cls": TwitterProfile
       "versions": Array [2]
       "relationships": Array [0]
       "_alias": male
```

So, keeping in mind that in this new DB I don't have the `id` field, the question is: What changes should I make to this query in order for this to work with my new DB?

I tried using only `_id` as in:

```
for profile in listProfiles:
     profile_id = db.mongo.get_one(collection='twitter_profile', where={'versions.screen_name':profile}, select={'_id':True})        
        listProfilesId.append(profile_id['_id'])
```

But it doesn't seen to be quite right as I get an error:

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

Thanks in advance for everyone trying to help and best regards,

Comment: You removed the 'id' attribute from the collection.  `_id` exists, but not `id`

Comment: Please use the [edit link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32843427/edit) to add the code and traceback to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @user3100115 , I already edited the question.